# Keyboard shortcuts for renaming file and accepting extension

Tags: macos, keyboard

When I try to rename a file (by pressing enter, then changing the extension of the file), it pops up with an alert asking "Are you sure you want to change the extensions ... " and the old extension is selected in blue. I haven't found a keyboard shortcut for selecting the new extension from the popup alert. Is there a way? I need to rename dozens of files, and doing it all through the keyboard would be so much quicker than selecting this one alert with a mouse.

Comment: Stop the warning entirely: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142607/how-do-i-stop-finder-from-warning-me-when-i-change-a-file-extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the prompt under Finder's Preferences (see picture below):

[image]

This might save you some time if you are renaming multiple files. Additionally, you may want to look at [Rename](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33659/rename). It is a free utility that should serve you well for such simple batch renaming.

Answer (score 3):

After trial-and-error, figured it out. It's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

There is no keyboard equivelant that I am aware of...

You could however use the terminal to make your life a little easier. If you need to rename the files one at a time, use the command

```
mv orig_file_name.ext new_file_name.newext
```

Comment: I discovered Cmd-U works for accepting the file extension change.

Comment: Nice!   I will have to try that.

Answer (score 1):

Those buttons highlighted in blue (e.g in your case "keep old") press enter; for those button with a blue background (e.g in your case "Use ...") press space bar.

[image: Extension Text Box]

Comment: Make sure that you have full keyboard access set to "All Controls" - ctrl + F7 toggles this feature

Comment: I kept Tabbing to the correct button then pressing Enter to select, but it would select the initial button. Great tip about Space Bar, and this is the true answer to this question.

Answer (score -2):

In Mountain Lion, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> works like a charm