# How do I stop Finder from warning me when I change a file extension?

Tags: macos, finder

When renaming a file in the Finder and changing the file extension, I get the following confirmation dialog warning message:

[image]

> Are you sure you want to change the extension from ".md" to ".txt"?
>
> If you make this change, your document may open in a different application.

How can I disable it?

Comment: Tip: when You want to make screenshot of a window press CMD+SHIFT+4 and hit space.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Finder > Preferences > Advanced (<kbd>⌘ ,</kbd>), then uncheck

> Show warning before changing an extension

[image]