# How to confirm Finder's rename prompt using the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, finder, macos

Using the keyboard, how can I confirm the rename prompt from Finder?

[image]

If I press <kbd>return</kbd>/<kbd>enter</kbd> the “Keep .doc” option is selected. Using the keyboard arrows <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> doesn't seems to help. Neither the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

Comment: you can disable this confirmation dialog entirely: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142607/how-do-i-stop-finder-from-warning-me-when-i-change-a-file-extension

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to enable all controls for <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and use it to switch the active button in application dialogs.

This can also be set in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I have this option turned on but if I press the COMMAND key and the first letter of the button text it selects that button.

Comment: @SteveChambers How does your comment relate to this answer?

Comment: In the question pressing COMMAND-U will confirm it

Comment: I have not written anything about Command-U and I don't think it is necessary in the method I described, thus I still don't understand, why do you write it as a comment under my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In latest MacOS version settings have changed:
You have to go to
Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard navigation and toggle the keyboard nav like this
[image: keyboard nav]

Comment: Please qualify what you mean by 'latest'. In 2 or 3 versions time your answer will be meaningless.