# Disable macOS Finder confirmation: "Are you sure you want to change the extension?"

Tags: macos, finder, file-extensions

Every time I change a file type in Finder, I'm forced to confirm that I actually want to change the file extension.

[image: change File Extension confirmation dialog]

> Are you sure you want to change the extension from ".old" to ".new"?
>
> If you make this change, your document may open in a different application.
>
> <kbd>Keep .old</kbd> <kbd>Use .new</kbd>

How can I stop going through this confirmation step?

Comment: This is a re-ask and modernization of the following question. That one was not coming up on Google when I went to find it. Feel free to mark as duplicate. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142607/how-do-i-stop-finder-from-warning-me-when-i-change-a-file-extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finder > Preferences > Advanced

> Show warning before changing an extension

[image]

Uncheck this option to disable the warning confirmation dialog when changing or renaming a file extension in the macOS Finder.